# В чем разница между двумя сочетаниями клавиш

Tags: visual-studio, ide, сборка, клавиатура

В чем разница между сочетаниями `F6` и `Ctrl - Shift - B` в Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию - никакой. Что то что то, по умолчанию, выполняет команду `Build solution`, ну или то что у Вас прописано в настройках. `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard`.

[image: VS Keyboard setup]